# Queue in RabbitMQ. Laravel. Getting error when i run worker: could not find driver (SQL: insert into `failed_jobs` ...)

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

Im using RabbitMQ for queue in Laravel and using "vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq" package.

I create a job and then I'm doing a dispatch. And when start the worker, I get an error in Laravel saying that the driver for working with the sql was not found.
SQL is used in the logic of my project.(i mean this "select * from `text` where `is_parsed` = 0 limit 1" in error text)

Error

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from `text` where `is_parsed` = 0 limit 1) in /var/www/zatesti_dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection .php:760

In env file in i changed QUEUE_CONNECTION =rabbitmq for "vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq" package.

Also i get error that it's impossible to write a failed job. As I understand it, it also needs to be written to a separate queue in the Rabbit

> [2022-11-10 11:11:28] local.ERROR: could not find driver (SQL: insert
> into `failed_jobs` (`uuid`, `connection`, `queue`, `payload`,
> `exception`,  `failed_at`)

Can anyone help how to fix the error with SQL driver and how to properly organize work with failed jobs?

Comment: I see you use `QUEUE_CONNECTION =rabbitmq` can you verify in `config/queue.php` that there is a `connection` named `rabbitmq`?

Comment: @Techno yes its the same. Dispath() function send job to rabbitmq correctly. But when I run worker its seems laravel confuse connections

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.
I call command

```
php artisan queue:work
```

not inside docker container.
when i run this command after make

```
docker exec -it appDev bash
```

its all work